# Visual Studio 2019 error on build C++ MySQL connector

Tags: c++, mysql, visual-studio, mysql-connector, connector

I downloaded libraries and headers from [Connector/C++ 8.0.26](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/cpp/) and tried all of them one by one, But always get error on building point.

I used Visual Studio 2019 (Version 16.10.0) and created a simple console app based on example from MySQL website. The original example is like this:

```
#include "mysql_connection.h"

#include <cppconn/driver.h>
#include <cppconn/exception.h>
#include <cppconn/resultset.h>
#include <cppconn/statement.h>

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
cout << endl;
cout << "Running 'SELECT 'Hello World!' »
   AS _message'..." << endl;

try {
  sql::Driver *driver;
  sql::Connection *con;
  sql::Statement *stmt;
  sql::ResultSet *res;

  /* Create a connection */
  driver = get_driver_instance();
  con = driver->connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:3306", "root", "root");
  /* Connect to the MySQL test database */
  con->setSchema("test");

  stmt = con->createStatement();
  res = stmt->executeQuery("SELECT 'Hello World!' AS _message");
  while (res->next()) {
    cout << "\t... MySQL replies: ";
    /* Access column data by alias or column name */
    cout << res->getString("_message") << endl;
    cout << "\t... MySQL says it again: ";
    /* Access column data by numeric offset, 1 is the first column */
    cout << res->getString(1) << endl;
  }
  delete res;
  delete stmt;
  delete con;

} catch (sql::SQLException &e) {
  cout << "# ERR: SQLException in " << __FILE__;
  cout << "(" << __FUNCTION__ << ") on line " »
     << __LINE__ << endl;
  cout << "# ERR: " << e.what();
  cout << " (MySQL error code: " << e.getErrorCode();
  cout << ", SQLState: " << e.getSQLState() << " )" << endl;
}

cout << endl;

return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I got same error with different configuration (32,64,Debug|release ....):

[image: error on build]

I read more than +100 topics here, also in other sites about same problem as well and try every solution that they provided but none of them work.

The only solution I not checked yet is to download the VS 2015 and try with that.

Now we are in 2021, is this really the right solution to create a C++/MySQL simple APP or I have to do something else?

Comment: The 2 errors about dllimport look like you did not link to the .lib file (import library) that goes with the dll

Comment: Visual Studio 2015 through 2019 are supposed to be binary compatible with a few exceptions: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/binary-compat-2015-2017?view=msvc-160](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/binary-compat-2015-2017?view=msvc-160)

Comment: @drescherjm I added x64 lib to aditional path in vs2019. is this what you mean or need doing other thing?

Comment: You should also have added at least 1 library to Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies setting of your project in each configuration (Debug, Release ... ) you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking all solution around the internet finally the problem solved by copying all `.dll` files to the `c:/windows` !

Comment: This is quite odd as dlls are not  at all involved in the build process for a native c++ application.

Comment: @drescherjm I agree with you, but this is the way that solved the problem for me.